# Disable or remove Bing in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, bing

First of all, this is only for the release version of Windows 8, not the beta, not RT nor any other version. If disabling the "Bing" subsystem is not possible then maybe there is a removal process? Either way I want it to stop interfering with everything I do with and on Google.

Comment: How does bing 'interfere with everything I do'? It just sits out of the way for me if I don't use it.

Comment: You'll up-vote once it happens to you after about a week of using windows 8. Expect to wait at least 60 seconds for Gmail to load in Chrome or IE. This is serious and I can't many who have started seeing it yet.

Comment: It is my assumption of course, since Bing is so deeply ingrained into windows 8. This does not happen in windows 7 or linux.

Comment: (Alright, I'm only trying to help) Are you sure it is related to bing? Have you tried uninstalling bing?

Comment: That's part of what I'm asking, is uninstalling it even possible?

Comment: Right click on the tile, click 'uninstall'

Comment: Also, i used gmail as the example in the comments but it affects any google domain on not just their own browser.

Comment: Well I've given an answer about uninstalling it if that's what you want.

Comment: I wanted to allow it (bing) to stay but if this is the only way then I'm fine with it.

Comment: It may not be bing, we need more details to know.

Comment: Uninstalling Windows will get rid of Bing as well. You should consider that option instead, because there are other components in Windows that interfere with "stuff", like Windows Media Player, Internet Explorer, etc.

Comment: I guess there should be a windows board on stackexchange so windows users can get help. The windows-haters aren't helping and if you can't help just move on instead of closing serious questions. You and the like may be the downfall of systems like this.

Comment: If you're referring to me as a "Windows-hater", no, I'm not a Windows-hater. I've been actually using Windows since version 3.1. I just don't agree that components of an OS interfere in "everything" someone does, so I was just being sarcastic. Sorry for that, won't do it ever again.

Comment: I refer directly to your "uninstalling windows" comment yes; clearly that was a jab? as if I am even interesting in doing that. Also good for you on 3.1; I've used windows 1.0 and every flavor of MS-DOS.

Comment: @Mondain can we keep this an on-topic question - not an opinionated argument.

Comment: @Mondain questions can be unclosed: if you make the question clear, add detailed examples of what goes wrong etc, the question can be opened.

Comment: I don't understand how it is interfering? I'm using Windows 8 from 2 months and it just stays out of the way if I don't open it. This is a vague question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uninstall Bing?

Right-click (swipe downwards in touch) on the tile, and hit uninstall.

If it isn't pinned to start, you can do exactly the same from the 'all apps' screen.

Comment: Ok, I did this.. now checking to see if its "fixed"

Comment: There is some improvement, especially in IE10; time to reboot the system in classic windows style

Comment: FYI this did help load time on google sites, but it breaks Windows Update... oh yay

Comment: @Mondain - If removing Bing broke your Windows Update then your installation is corrupt because I was able to remove Bing on my system, and it didn't affect anything.

Comment: Have you tried 'refresh your PC'?

Comment: Gotta say I'm scared to do a refresh, I think I'll just suffer through until my work PC arrives; no more windows 8 purchases for me though until SP1. I broke my own rule by buying in too early with the 2 copies I have. :(

Comment: There's nothing to be scared about, everything will be kept, it just replaces your core windows files.

Comment: Thanks @Tek, I'll have to read up on that as I thought it "reset" everything

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/01/04/refresh-and-reset-your-pc.aspx

Comment: Refresh has fixed the issues I was having for now, the only catch is that "refresh" deletes all your apps but it does write an html page to tell you what apps were removed with some of them having links to their sites (minus the google links).